# Sitecore 9.0 Migrating the Sitecore Items from Sitecore 8.1 to Sitecore 9.0

Tags: sitecore-client

I am trying to migrate sitecore items from sitecore 8.1 to Sitecore 9.0, we tried by creating package and serialization both attempts it has failed. We cant take the database backup and proceed because of the client guidelines. Can any one suggest the best approach for the same.

Thanks 
Shrinivasan

Comment: I think you are trying to take huge number of items in a single package. Divide the items in to multiple package and then it should work

Comment: As @HimanshuAgarwal suggest this can be one problem but are you getting any error during this? by you mean migrate is just content or you are upgrading the Sitecore version.

Comment: Explain the failures? what's happened? beside the size. keep in mind there are rights on items and references

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend two tools here:

1. [Sitecore Express Migration tool](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Express_Migration_Tool.aspx) is an official application from Sitecore. I prefer this tool (especially for 8 to 9 upgrades when it provides additional steps to prevent well know issues) since this works with SQL databases only and it is very fast, but it will require manual reindexing, etc. I've upgraded both Sitecore 8.1 to Sitecore 9.2 and Sitecore 9.0.2 to Sitecore 9.2 using this tool without any issues.
2. [Sitecore Sidekick](https://github.com/JeffDarchuk/SitecoreSidekick) that is often used by my teammates during Sitecore upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend on eof the following two approaches

1. Install https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Razl and merge the content of sitecore 8.2 database to 9.0
2. package the templates,Layouts/renderings,images,custom rules/settings,pages and content items(data source items) as seperate packages and install it on the vanilla sitecore 9 version.You can also serialize the same sections mentioned from old database and deserialize it to new database